# Vector tile layers over 3D terrain

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

I have a set of vector tile layers I'm hosting (mbtiles) on Mapbox.

Currently, I'm using Leaflet to overlay these on a 2D satellite view and works.

However I'm wanting to add in some features to my site that Leaflet doesn't support (namely rotate and tilting for 3D terrain). I'd love to be able to use Google maps satellite view with its rotation and 3D views of mountains, etc.

Is there a way to add vector tile layers using the Google Maps API?

Maybe the best solution is to switch to Mapbox-GL-JS for the rotate/tilt and give up on the 3D terrain?

Comment: not sure if googles unlimited funded brains have done some magic already, but *as of yet* and AFAIK, draping vectors, other than points, over 3D terrain is too hardware demanding as a render process to be practcal for real-time visalisations in WebGL. *cesium* uses (and tries to standardize) a 3DTile format based on TopoJSON that might be the tec to use in the near future.